# Need examples of some well written jQuery plugins

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have seen people writing jQuery plugins in different styles. Some authors use a private `methods` object (within a closure) and invoke the method using `methods[fn].call(this, args)` style. There are other who create a new object of a private class, and invoke the method like `this.fn()`. Few other use `ui.widget` as the base for their plugin.

Which of these methods would you suggest for a plugin? I am not interested in using `ui.widget`, because it is an extra dependency, which can be avoided. Can anyone suggest some well written jQuery plugins, which will help me write better plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if mine are well written or not. I kept it very simple at first then gradually added functionality to allow for instance manipulation etc. The ones I wrote are terse if that's what you mean by well written and they do get a lot of downloads.

Just search on dumbFormState and dumbCrossFade or "how to create plugins that are instance aware" and you will find my writings and code.

The first thing you must do to have the possibility of being great is knowing your sh**.

1) Watch Douglas Crockford videos over and over until it sticks. He is brilliant. I cannot stress this first one enough.
2) Study popular jQuery plugin implementations since after looking at Crockford, you will get it.
3) Go through John Resig's Advanced JavaScript Tutorial. He is brilliant. I cannot stress this enough.

The road to learning this is not easy however, if you go deep and you will reap.

Comment: Thanks. I have written a few instance aware plugins for a few sites. I have always used `methods[fn].call (this, args)` from within the `$.fn.plugin` constructor and it always works. I wanted to know, if there were better ways of doing this. Thanks for the pointers, i will go through them.

Comment: Which plugins have you written? I am in need of some smart folks as I run emeraldcode.com and kitgui.com and both are heavy in jQuery.

Comment: I have written a few plugins, but haven't released them to public (too lazy to write documentation), even though I have plans to do that. Here are some of them

Comment: Overlay ($.overlay), Modal Window($.fn.modal), Tooltip($.fn.tooltip) http://bit.ly/v7DO7C

Comment: Adds Google transliteration to a textarea / contenteditable element $.translit() http://bit.ly/sa62XG

Comment: Allows a regular textarea to be converted into a tinymce / ACE editor, with links to switch between the different modes http://bit.ly/vDQgr3

Comment: Here is a demo for another. Type your name in the text field http://bit.ly/rvsS5s

Comment: ok I like this style of programming. I too use closures for compartmentalizing my code. You have an odesk handle? KitGUI is pretty advanced coding but you look like you could handle it. I wish I found your stuff sooner. I've had to bring people up to speed and looks like you are up to speed already.